# Reduce the number of lines inside the loop

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop

I have this code:

```
while count < len(dist_list):
    new.loc[base, "1_dist"],  new.loc[base, "1_t-"]= dist_list[0], new.loc[base, "t-"]
    new.loc[base, "2_dist"],  new.loc[base, "2_t-"]= dist_list[1], new.loc[base, "t-"]
    new.loc[base, "3_dist"],  new.loc[base, "3_t-"]= dist_list[2], new.loc[base, "t-"]
    new.loc[base, "4_dist"],  new.loc[base, "4_t-"]= dist_list[3], new.loc[base, "t-"]
    new.loc[base, "5_dist"],  new.loc[base, "5_t-"]= dist_list[4], new.loc[base, "t-"]
    new.loc[base, "6_dist"],  new.loc[base, "6_t-"]= dist_list[5], new.loc[base, "t-"]
    new.loc[base, "7_dist"],  new.loc[base, "7_t-"]= dist_list[6], new.loc[base, "t-"]
    new.loc[base, "8_dist"],  new.loc[base, "8_t-"]= dist_list[7], new.loc[base, "t-"]
    new.loc[base, "9_dist"],  new.loc[base, "9_t-"]= dist_list[8], new.loc[base, "t-"]
    new.loc[base, "10_dist"],  new.loc[base, "10_t-"]= dist_list[9], new.loc[base, "t-"]
    count += 1
```

I need to do the same code, but with 100 variables (1_dist, 2_dist... 100_dist). Manually, I will have 100 rows inside the loop. But I'm looking for a way to make this process with fewer rows.

Does anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while count < len(dist_list):
new.loc[base, f"{count + 1}_dist"],  new.loc[base, f"{count + 1}_t-"]= dist_list[count], new.loc[base, "t-"]
count += 1
```

I don't quite understand the code but seeing as you wrote those 10 lines it seems you want to go 1 more that count in 1st 2 string and then in 3rd (when giving index to a list maybe) you want it as same as count.

Answer (score 2):

You are already iterating over `dist_list`, so you might as well use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and use that index instead of manually maintaining `count`:

```py
for index, data in enumerate(data_list, 1):
    new.loc[base, f"{index}_dist"], new.loc[base, f"{index}_t-"] = data, new.loc[base, "t-"]
```